# How do I prevent hotlining but allow google in nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy, googlebot, hotlinking

I want to setup a reverse proxy for serving images stored in S3.
I dont want to allow access to images if `referrer` is not `example.com` 
But I want to allow multiple crawlers for example google bot, bing bot etc (based on `user_agent`) to access the images.
I also want to allow my android app to access the images (based on custom header say `X-Application: ExampleApp`)

How do I configure nginx to do so ?

Comment: The referrer header can be faked. Are you okay with that?

Comment: Yes I am ok with faked header. I dont want to protect images. I just want to stop other sites from using my bandwith.

Answer (score 1):

That comes to using 3 IF's which is not going to work due to IF limitations.
What you can do is 2 things, set up MAP to deal with the 3 tests (setting true or false values) then inside the server block use Lua to combine the 3 test values into one and use a single IF (or pure Lua) in the location block to allow/deny access.

```
map $referrer $usestring1 {
 default     0;
 ~^google$   1;
}
map $user_agent $usestring2 {
 default     0;
 ~^google$   1;
}
etc....

location / {
    content_by_lua '
      local s = ngx.var.usestring1;
      local t = ngx.var.usestring2;
      if s+t == 2 then return ngx.exit(503); end;
    ';
  etc...........
```